# resolution come very bad after image stitching

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

i am working on a project to detect football players in the playground by computer vision using fasterRCNN, but i take the input frames from three different cameras (left, mid, right), so i have applied image stitching before applying the forward detection, but the stitched output is viewed noisy and the players appeared very far because of that the forward detection network can detect only the very close players.

[image: this the output of the stitching phase]

anyone familiar with image processing and computer vision can help me to improve the quality of the image above to improve the detection results.

Comment: Hi! Want to help out but there's a lot of details about this project you're leaving out. How is your model performing? What kind of labels are you producing? What is your original image size? What kind of image stitching are you performing and how is it being done with your labels? Code? Etc.

Comment: produce a higher-resolution picture. that is all. -- if you need the humans on the green to be closer in "apparent" height, you'd need to move the camera further away from the field. -- you don't need that though, the neural network just needs to be given higher-resolution data.